# Filter function inside For Each SwiftUI

Tags: swift, loops, swiftui

I am trying to filter through data that I have retrieved from an API based on a model of car, I have a @State that holds an empty string initially and will update based on what the user has typed. I can't figure out how to filter the data based on the input inside of my existing ForEach loop, any help would be appreciated

```js
import SwiftUI

struct HomeView: View {
  @EnvironmentObject var users: Network
  let columns = [
    GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 150))
  ]
  @State var isActive: Bool = false
  @State private var shouldAnimate = false
  @State var show = false
  @State private var searchText = ""
  @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme
    var searchResults: [Car] {
        let searchModel = String(searchText)
        return searchModel == nil ? users.users : users.users.filter{$0.model == searchModel}
    }

    
  var body: some View {
    ScrollView {

      if self.users.users.count > 0 {
        Text("All \(self.users.users[1].make) vehicles")
          .bold()
          .textCase(.uppercase)
          .font(.headline)
      } else {
        Spacer()
        Spacer()
        HStack(alignment: VerticalAlignment.center) {
          Circle()
            .fill(shouldAnimate ? Color.orange : Color.white)
            .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
            .scaleEffect(shouldAnimate ? 1.0 : 0.5)
            .animation(
              Animation.easeInOut(duration: 0.5).repeatForever(autoreverses: true), value: show)
          Circle()
            .fill(shouldAnimate ? Color.orange : Color.white)
            .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
            .scaleEffect(shouldAnimate ? 1.0 : 0.5)
            .animation(
              Animation.easeInOut(duration: 0.5).repeatForever(autoreverses: true).delay(0.3),
              value: show)

          Circle()
            .fill(shouldAnimate ? Color.orange : Color.white)
            .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
            .scaleEffect(shouldAnimate ? 1.0 : 0.5)
            .animation(
              Animation.easeInOut(duration: 0.5).repeatForever(autoreverses: true).delay(0.6),
              value: show)
        }
        Spacer()
        VStack {
          Text("Retrieving the Data...")
            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
            .textCase(.uppercase)
        }

      }
      SearchBar(text: $searchText)
        .padding(.top, -30)
      LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: 10) {
        ForEach(searchResults) { car in
          if car.year >= 2017 {
            HStack(alignment: .top) {
                
              VStack {
                Image(systemName: "car.fill")
                  .resizable()
                  .scaledToFit()
                  .frame(width: 140.0, height: 70)
                  .foregroundColor(.white)

                Text(car.model ?? "lol")
                  .font(.system(size: 15, weight: .bold, design: .default))
                  .foregroundColor(colorScheme == .dark ? Color.white : Color.black)
                  .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)

                Text(String(car.year))
                  .font(.system(size: 16, weight: .regular, design: .default))
                  .foregroundColor(.orange)
                  .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)

                Text(car.make)
                  .font(.system(size: 16, weight: .bold, design: .default))
                  .foregroundColor(colorScheme == .dark ? Color.white : Color.gray)
                  .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)

              }

              .frame(height: 250)
              .background(colorScheme == .dark ? Color.black.opacity(0.2) : Color.white)
              .cornerRadius(20)
              .padding()
              .clipped()
              .shadow(color: Color.black.opacity(0.24), radius: 10, x: 0, y: 0)

            }
          }
        }
      }

    }
    .background(colorScheme == .dark ? Color.black.opacity(0.1) : Color.white)

    .onAppear {
      users.getCars()
      self.shouldAnimate = true
      self.show = true
    }
  }
}
struct HomeView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    HomeView()
      .environmentObject(Network())
  }
}
```

Data:

```js
[
    {
        "id": 1119,
        "make": "Audi",
        "model": "100",
        "generation": "100 Avant (4A,C4)",
        "engine_modification": "2.8 V6 E (174 Hp) quattro Automatic",
        "year": 1991,
        "powertrain_architecture": "Internal Combustion engine",
        "body_type": "Station wagon (estate)",
        "number_of_seats": 5,
        "number_of_doors": 5,
        "urban_fuel_consumption": 13.5,
        "extra_urban_fuel_consumption": 8,
        "combined_fuel_consumption": 10,
        "fuel_type": "Petrol (Gasoline)",
        "acceleration": 9.5,
        "top_speed": 207,
        "power": 174,
        "torque": 250,
        "engine_location": "Front, Longitudinal",
        "engine_displacement": 2771,
        "number_of_cylinders": 6,
        "position_of_cylinders": "V-engine",
        "number_of_valves_per_cylinder": 2,
        "fuel_system": "Multi-point indirect injection",
        "engine_aspiration": "Naturally aspirated engine",
        "kerb_weight": 1550,
        "fuel_tank_capacity": 80,
        "drive_wheel": "All wheel drive (4x4)",
        "number_of_gears": 4,
        "front_brakes": "Ventilated discs",
        "rear_brakes": "Disc"
    },
    {
        "id": 1120,
        "make": "Audi",
        "model": "100",
        "generation": "100 Avant (4A,C4)",
        "engine_modification": "2.8 V6 E (174 Hp) quattro",
        "year": 1991,
        "powertrain_architecture": "Internal Combustion engine",
        "body_type": "Station wagon (estate)",
        "number_of_seats": 5,
        "number_of_doors": 5,
        "urban_fuel_consumption": 13.5,
        "extra_urban_fuel_consumption": 8,
        "combined_fuel_consumption": 10,
        "fuel_type": "Petrol (Gasoline)",
        "acceleration": null,
        "top_speed": null,
        "power": 174,
        "torque": 250,
        "engine_location": "Front, Longitudinal",
        "engine_displacement": 2771,
        "number_of_cylinders": 6,
        "position_of_cylinders": "V-engine",
        "number_of_valves_per_cylinder": 2,
        "fuel_system": "Multi-point indirect injection",
        "engine_aspiration": "Naturally aspirated engine",
        "kerb_weight": 1550,
        "fuel_tank_capacity": 80,
        "drive_wheel": "All wheel drive (4x4)",
        "number_of_gears": 5,
        "front_brakes": "Ventilated discs",
        "rear_brakes": "Disc"
    },
```

users.users

```js
import Foundation

struct Car: Hashable,Codable, Identifiable {
    let id : Int?
    var make: String
    var model: String?
    var generation: String?
    var engine_modification: String?
    var year: Int 
    var powertrain_architecture: String?
    var body_type: String?
    var number_of_seats: Int?
    var number_of_doors: Int?
    var urban_fuel_consumption: Double?
    var extra_urban_fuel_consumption: Double?
    var combined_fuel_consumption: Double?
    var fuel_type: String?
    var acceleration: Double? // was Int
    var top_speed: Int? // was Int
    var power: Int?
    var torque: Int?
    var engine_location: String?
    var engine_displacement: Int?
    var number_of_cylinders: Int?
    var position_of_cylinders: String?
    var number_of_valves_per_cylinder: Int?
    var fuel_system: String?
    var engine_aspiration: String?
    var kerb_weight: Int?
    var fuel_tank_capacity: Double?
    var drive_wheel: String?
    var number_of_gears: Int?
    var front_brakes: String?
    var rear_brakes: String?
}
```

Comment: have a look at my answer to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73629297/using-searchbar-to-dynamically-show-data-in-swiftui-from-an-array/73629717#73629717

Comment: can you show what `users.users` in the `ForEach` loop is. Is it an array of `[Car]`?

Comment: It is an Array of [Car] :)

Comment: Some of the naming is still off due to experimentation, my apologies if its messy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try something like this example code, assuming you want to search by year:

```
@State var searchText = ""

var searchResults: [Car] {
    let searchYear = Int(searchText)
    searchYear == nil ? users.users : users.users.filter{$0.year == searchYear!}
}

var body: some View {
    // ...
    SearchBar(text: $searchText)
    // ...
    LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: 10) {
        ForEach(searchResults) { car in
            HStack(alignment: .top) {
                VStack {
                    // ...
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT-1: to search for car model, try this:

```
var searchResults: [Car] {
    searchText.isEmpty ? users.users : users.users.filter{
        $0.model == nil ? false : $0.model!.contains(searchText)
    }
}
```

EDIT-2: here is the code I used in my tests, to show that the approach  works:

```
struct Car: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var year: Int
    var make: String
    var model: String?
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var cars = [Car(year: 123, make: "aaa", model: "bbb"),
                       Car(year: 456, make: "cc", model: "dd"),
                       Car(year: 789, make: "eee", model: "dd")]
    
    @State private var searchText = ""
    
    var searchResults: [Car] {
        searchText.isEmpty ? cars : cars.filter{
            $0.model == nil ? false : $0.model!.contains(searchText)
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List (searchResults) { car in
                Text(car.model ?? "no data")
            }
        }
        .searchable(text: $searchText)
    }
}
```

Comment: At this point nothing gets returned, it says Comparing a non-optional value of String to nil will always return false

Comment: show the code that reproduces your error, not just the little bit that you show. Show which line has the error, and the full error message. In other words, show more of your code.

Comment: updated my answer in view of your new code.